# Safe cross thread calling error

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

Am calling the following code from backgroundworker, but instead of setting the desired text, it add the application caption to the lisbox
what is wrong with it

```
 Private Sub SetStatus(ByVal sStatus As String)
        If Me.lsbLog.InvokeRequired Then
            Dim d As New SetTextCallback(AddressOf SetStatus)
            Me.lsbLog.Invoke(d, New Object() {[Text]})
            '// Me.Invoke(Sub() SetStatus(sStatus))
        Else
            If Mid$(LCase$(sStatus), 1, 4) = "sent" Then
                tslSent.Text = "Sent:" & FormatNumber(lSent, 0, TriState.False)
            Else
                lsbLog.Items.Add(sStatus)
            End If
        End If

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You pick up the form's `Text` property when you invoke the delegate (`...New Object() {[Text]} ...`). You want to sent the `sStatus` argument in the delegate call instead:

```
If Me.lsbLog.InvokeRequired Then
    Dim d As New SetTextCallback(AddressOf SetStatus)
    Me.lsbLog.Invoke(d, New Object() {sStatus})
    ''# ...and so on
```